# How to group the list based on category in listview xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have to group the list in listview based on category like Bird,Fish,Animal..etc in Xamarin.Forms PCL Project. Please give any reference tutorial or demo code.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: Remember to tell us what you've already tried.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find good XF sample [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/LabelledSectionsList)